# How to calculate sum of multiple columns value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm training to calculate a new "Total" column from three new columns that I already calculated in my query, see below:

```
 SELECT TOP 500 request_key
      ,request_id
      ,CreatedTime
      ,AssignTime
      ,IssueTime
      ,CloseTime
      ,RequestDetails
      ,request_type
      ,Product
      ,SiteName
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, createdtime, AssignTime + 1) AS Idle
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AssignTime, IssueTime + 1) AS Assign
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IssueTime, CloseTime +1 ) AS Delegate

FROM [wombat].[dbo].[VwWombatCrossSiteCorrelationReport]
```

The new "Total" column should have the next data: Idle + Assign + Delegate

Comment: I tagged the question SQL Server based on the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could, of course, just repeat the calculations that produced `Idle`, `Assign` and `Delegate`, but, well.. yuck. Another option would be to use this query as a subquery to avoid having to repeat calculations:

```
SELECT *, Idle + Assign + Delegate AS Total
FROM   (SELECT TOP 500 request_key,
                       request_id,
                       CreatedTime,
                       AssignTime,
                       IssueTime,
                       CloseTime,
                       RequestDetails,
                       request_type,
                       Product,
                       SiteName,
                       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, createdtime, AssignTime + 1) AS Idle,
                       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AssignTime, IssueTime + 1) AS Assign,
                       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IssueTime, CloseTime +1 ) AS Delegate
        FROM [wombat].[dbo].[VwWombatCrossSiteCorrelationReport]) t
```

Comment: Thanks!! that what I tried to do all day long but I forgot the "t" at the end.
what "t" purpose here?

Comment: `t` is a table alias for the inner query. Some [tag:rdbms]s (such as Oracle) allow you to omit it if you don't directly use it. In MS SQL Server, however, however, it's mandatory to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, createdtime, AssignTime + 1) AS Idle
      + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AssignTime, IssueTime + 1) AS Assign
        + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IssueTime, CloseTime +1 ) AS Delegate) AS total
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can do this because "idle, assign & delegate" are new columns that I calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make it simple and add another calculated column:

```
SELECT TOP 500 request_key
      ,request_id
      ,CreatedTime
      ,AssignTime
      ,IssueTime
      ,CloseTime
      ,RequestDetails
      ,request_type
      ,Product
      ,SiteName
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, createdtime, AssignTime + 1) AS Idle
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AssignTime, IssueTime + 1) AS Assign
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IssueTime, CloseTime +1 ) AS Delegate
     , Total = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, createdtime, AssignTime + 1) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AssignTime, IssueTime + 1) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IssueTime, CloseTime +1 )
 FROM [wombat].[dbo].[VwWombatCrossSiteCorrelationReport]
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to do this uses `outer apply`:

```
SELECT TOP 500 cr.*, v.idle, v.assign, v.delegate,
       (v.idle + v.assign + v.delegate) as Total
FROM [wombat].[dbo].[VwWombatCrossSiteCorrelationReport] cr outer apply
     (select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, createdtime, AssignTime + 1) as Idle,
             DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AssignTime, IssueTime + 1) as Assign,
             DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IssueTime, CloseTime +1 ) as Delegate
     ) v;
```